# Spherical Voronoi diagram, binary splitting approach

Tags: performance, perl, geospatial, google-maps

**EDIT: My code DOES not work, see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/294380/if-rectangle-corner-points-have-same-nearest-neighbor-does-whole-interior**

Given 5 (currently hardcoded) cities, this code uses Google Maps to
split the world into 5 regions, each region being the points closer to
a given city than to the other 4.

[It works](http://test.barrycarter.info/gmap8.php), but is slow in two senses:

- The program takes a long time to run, especially when `$minarea` is small.
- The program generates *many* polygons, slowing down the Google Map above. With smaller '$minarea', I've even run out of JavaScript stack space.

Thought: Would something w/ qhull be faster?

The `bvoronoi` subroutine does most of the work:

```
#!/bin/perl

# Unusual approach to Voronoi diagram of Earth sphere: cut into 4
# pieces and compare closest point for 4 vertices

# TODO: this program is long and clumsy and can doubtless be improved

use POSIX;

# defining constants here is probably bad
$PI = 4.*atan(1);
$EARTH_RADIUS = 6371/1.609344; # miles

open(A,">/home/barrycarter/BCINFO/sites/TEST/gvorbin.txt");

# latitude and longitude of points
%points = (
 "Albuquerque" => "35.08 -106.66",
 "Paris" => "48.87 2.33",
 "Barrow" => "71.26826 -156.80627",
 "Wellington" => "-41.2833 174.783333",
 "Rio" => "-22.88  -43.28"
);

# primartish colors
%colors = (
 "Albuquerque" => "#ff0000",
 "Paris" => "#00ff00",
 "Barrow" => "#0000ff",
 "Wellington" => "#ffff00",
 "Rio" => "#ff00ff",
 "BORDER" => "#000000"
);

# stop at what gridsize
$minarea = .5;

# the four psuedo-corners of the globe
$nw = bvoronoi(0,90,-180,0);
$ne = bvoronoi(0,90,0,180);
$sw = bvoronoi(-90,0,-180,0);
$se = bvoronoi(-90,0,0,180);

for $i (split("\n","$nw\n$ne\n$sw\n$se")) {
  # create google filled box
  my($latmin, $latmax, $lonmin, $lonmax, $closest) = split(/\s+/, $i);

  # build up the coords
  print A << "MARK";

var myCoords = [
 new google.maps.LatLng($latmin, $lonmin),
 new google.maps.LatLng($latmin, $lonmax),
 new google.maps.LatLng($latmax, $lonmax),
 new google.maps.LatLng($latmax, $lonmin),
 new google.maps.LatLng($latmin, $lonmin)
];

myPoly = new google.maps.Polygon({
 paths: myCoords,
 strokeColor: "$colors{$closest}",
 strokeOpacity: 1,
 strokeWeight: 0,
 fillColor: "$colors{$closest}",
 fillOpacity: 0.5
});

myPoly.setMap(map);

MARK
;

}

# workhorse function: given a "square" (on an equiangular map),
# determine the closest point of 4 vertices; if same, return square
# and point; otherwise, break square into 4 squares and recurse

sub bvoronoi {
  # Using %points as global is ugly
  my($latmin, $latmax, $lonmin, $lonmax) = @_;
  my($mindist, $dist, %closest);

  # compute distance to each %points for each corner
  # TODO: this is wildly inefficient, since I just need relative
  # distance, not exact!
  for $lat ($latmin,$latmax) {
    for $lon ($lonmin,$lonmax) {
      # TODO: has to be easier way to do this?
      $mindist = 0; $dist= 0;
      for $point (keys %points) {
        my($plat,$plon) = split(/\s+/, $points{$point});
        $dist = gcdist($lat, $lon, $plat, $plon);
        if ($dist < $mindist || !$mindist) {
          $mindist = $dist;
          $minpoint = $point;
        }
      }
      # this point is closest to one vertex of the square
      # TODO: should abort loop if we already have two different closest points
      $closest{$minpoint} = 1;
    }
  }

  # if there's just one point closest to all four corners, return it
  my(@keys) = keys %closest;

  # if @keys has length 1, return it
  unless ($#keys) {
    return "$latmin $latmax $lonmin $lonmax $keys[0]";
  }

  # if we've hit a border point, return it (area too small)
  my($area) = ($latmax-$latmin)*($lonmax-$lonmin);

  if ($area <= $minarea) {
    return "$latmin $latmax $lonmin $lonmax BORDER";
  }

  # split square and recurse
  my($latmid) = ($latmax+$latmin)/2.;
  my($lonmid) = ($lonmax+$lonmin)/2.;

  my(@sub) = ();
  push(@sub, bvoronoi($latmin, $latmid, $lonmin, $lonmid));
  push(@sub, bvoronoi($latmid, $latmax, $lonmin, $lonmid));
  push(@sub, bvoronoi($latmin, $latmid, $lonmid, $lonmax));
  push(@sub, bvoronoi($latmid, $latmax, $lonmid, $lonmax));

  return join("\n", @sub);
}

=item gcdist($x,$y,$u,$v)

Great circle distance between latitude/longitude x,y and
latitude/longitude u,v in miles Source: http://williams.best.vwh.net/avform.htm

=cut

sub gcdist {
    my(@x)=@_;
    my($x,$y,$u,$v)=map {$_*=$PI/180} @x;
    my($c1) = cos($x)*cos($y)*cos($u)*cos($v);
    my($c2) = cos($x)*sin($y)*cos($u)*sin($v);
    my($c3) = sin($x)*sin($u);
    return ($EARTH_RADIUS*acos($c1+$c2+$c3));
}
```

[Another failed approach](https://github.com/barrycarter/bcapps/blob/master/bc-closest-gmap.pl)

EDIT: Thanks to whoever upvoted this. I've now fixed the http://test.barrycarter.info/gmap8.php link and am including a screenshot below:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, try [cssgrid](http://ngwww.ucar.edu/ngmath/cssgrid/csshome.html) from [NCAR Graphics](http://ngwww.ucar.edu/).

At length:

There's [a similar question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/545870/algorithm-to-compute-a-voronoi-diagram-on-a-sphere), but it has no accepted answer.

So here's an answer, if you'll permit two apologies. 1. I'll leave the Google Maps work to you. 2. I didn't read your code thoroughly.

The algorithm's running time should be no higher in order than sorting, O(n log n). At least, "[Voronoi diagrams on the sphere](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0925-7721(02)00077-9)", openly available as a [Utrecht University report](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.19.6737), claims that that result is in [Kevin Quintin Brown's dissertation](http://wwwlib.umi.com/dissertations/fullcit/8012772). Furthermore "[On the construction of the Voronoi mesh on a sphere](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0021-9991(85)90140-8)" claims in its abstract to construct the mesh in O(n).

It looks like qhull doesn't do all that you need, but I found something else. [The cssgrid package is found in the GPL-licensed NCAR Graphics software](http://ngwww.ucar.edu/whatsnew.html#WhatsNew4_2_0) and does what you need, with C, Fortran, and NCAR-specific bindings. You can download all of [NCAR Graphics](http://ngwww.ucar.edu/) from its page at the (United States) National Center for Atmospheric Research. If you wish, you can use SWIG to make the relevant C binding available to Perl.

The [cssgrid](http://ngwww.ucar.edu/ngmath/cssgrid/csshome.html) package has its own documentation page online. The functions *csvoro* (Voronoi) and *css2c* (spherical to cartesian, that is, latitude-longitude to X-Y-Z coordinates) are the most relevant ones.

The cssgrid package is based on STRIPACK by permission of STRIPACK's author. STRIPACK comes up higher in web searches and is cost-free for noncommercial use. However, STRIPACK itself as an ACM TOMS algorithm is [neither public domain nor GPL-compatible](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/design/gsl-design.html). Also it is Fortran 90 code without a provided C binding, although that difficulty might be surmountable using FortWrap.